# Converting VirtualBox .VDI .VHD .VMDK to bootable .iso file

Tags: virtualbox, iso, dd, bootable, vdi

The title is pretty much describe it all.

I thought it would be an extremely easy task but I'm googling the topic for a few days and can not find a proper solution.

I succeed convert it to .iso but it's not bootable from a physical machine.

I have tried:

```
VBoxManage clonehd file.vdi output.iso --format RAW
```

I have tried:

```
VBoxManage clonemedium --format RAW gangina.vdi gangina.img
```

I have tried:

```
qemu-img convert -f vpc -O raw gangina.vhd gangina.raw
```

I have also tried to mount the bootable vdi file and:

```
sudo dd if={mountedDirectory} of=gangina.iso status=progress
```

Unfortunately none of them is actually bootable from a physical machine.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot DD with a mounted directory.

You can dd the partition, but it would work better to dd the entire drive.

example: dd sudo dd if={/dev/sda} of=filename.iso status=progress

I am assuming you are on a Linux machine, but when you get it write to a USB and plug it in and boot it. I have used this method before with much success.

While you can do just a partition say sda1 or sda2 dd'ing the entire drive will achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: If you take a block-by-block image of your hard drive, it is _not_ an `.iso` file. Naming it one doesn't change that. It's an `.img` or `.bin` file, at best. And while it is possible to copy filesystems and even entire disks like that, beware of pitfalls like the fact that you'll now have two sets of identical partitions with the same labels and UUIDs, which will confuse the crap out of your OS if you attach them both at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your bootable .VDI .VHD and .VMDK souce to BOOTABLE .iso or .img on follow way on Linux like p.e. Ubuntu, Mint or Debian:

Convert to .iso step 1of2: Convert to .raw:

```
qemu-img convert -f vdi source_image.vdi -O raw destination_image.raw

qemu-img convert -f vhd source_image.vhd -O raw destination_image.raw

qemu-img convert -f vmdk source_image.vmdk -O raw destination_image.raw
```

Convert to .iso, step 2of2: Convert .raw to iso:

```
mkisofs -o destination_image.iso source_image.raw
```

Convert .vdi to .img

```
qemu-img convert -f vdi -O raw source_image.vdi destination_image.img
```

Convert .vhd to .img

```
qemu-img convert -f vhd -O raw source_image.vhd destination_image.img
```

Convert .vmdk to .img

```
qemu-img convert -f vmdk -O raw source_image.vmdk destination_image.img
```

Comment: first 3 are the same for vdi; should they be vhd and vmdk

Comment: `qemu-img convert -f vhd source_image.vhd -O raw destination_image.raw` errors with Unknown driver 'vhd' , apparently the driver name for vhd files is **vpc**, so the command would be `qemu-img convert -f vpc source_image.vhd -O raw destination_image.raw`